# Google keeps refreshing itself constantly in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When searching for anything in Google, it keeps refreshing itself; or, rather, it keeps redirecting itself between the url variants `https://www.google.hu/search?q=<query>&cad=h` and `https://www.google.hu/#newwindow=1&q=<query>`. It just keeps ping-ponging between these, like in an old-fashioned redirect loop, except it never ends.

Needless to say, it's very annoying.

This is happening using Google Chrome 48.0.2564.71 beta 64 bit, on a Lubuntu installation, with 16 GB of memory (and no history of RAM troubles). Tried to install a stable version over it (though not --purge-ing the original, so with the same settings) and the same thing happened. No other pages show this behaviour.

Tried to clear browsing history, cookies and cache: it did help, but only for two searches, then the issue resurfaced. Things work fine in Incognito mode or when I'm not logged in to my Google account.

Looking around on the internet yielded [this bug report](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/9hnk9XVsGY0) and variants, which describe a bug about Chrome keeping refreshing every page, which sounds similar, but isn't the same. 'Instant search' was alread disabled.

Now, I realize the problem would perhaps go away if I deleted every little piece of Chrome from the computer, but I'm not sure, and if possible I'd like to keep my various settings. Does anyone have an idea as to how to achieve that?

Comment: uninstall the google chrome and restart your computer and re-install the google chrome again.

Answer (score 1):

Check your extensions. You may have to incrementally turn them off until you identify which one is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can actually backup the chrome user directory and copy the user directory after you reinstall on your new machine.

By default chrome saves user-data in this location (unless you changed it in cla setting --user-data): 
C:\Documents and Settings[your name]\Local Settings\Application Data\Chrome\User Data

Just backup that whole directory and restore it when you install in your new machine.